# Slow menu and icon issue in the launcher with LibreOffice 4.1

Tags: libreoffice

I've updated via the official PPA to 4.1.0.4. I've noticed the menubar in Libreoffice 4.1 takes quite long to populate and also when opening a file from Nautilus or the dash it does not associate with the icon on the launcher. How can I fix this or revert back to the original Ubuntu version? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem with menu delay...

Comment: I had that too. In addition, it was not possible to switch to LO windows via Alt-Tab or from the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I had this and additional problems - Impress actually locked up my computer when I opened a specific file - and I got into a lot of headaches when I rolled back.  Here is the right way to do it. From terminal:

> sudo apt-get autoremove libreoffice (do NOT remove the PPA first!)

Now go to Ubuntu Software Center, Edit | Sources | Other Software and remove the PPA for LibreOffice

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libreoffice

Comment: The libreoffice meta package was not installed when I updated from the PPA so the the first command returns "Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed." Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The recommended way to remove a PPA is to run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:repository-name/subdirectory` (the OP didn't specify which LO PPA was used). Please see http://askubuntu.com/a/313/8973 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Does anybody know whether there is a bug report for that? I found this one which looks quite similar:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1173889

But it has been marked as fixed in 4.1.0, and we're all using 4.1.0.4.

It's really annoying to click on "File" or "Help" and to have to wait 5 seconds until entries show up...

Comment: I mean it was marked fixed in 4.1.0 on August 6th, and I don't remember updating anything since then, so the solution could be coming, but isn't 4.1.0.4 after 4.1.0? I couldn't find any information in the LO release calendar on that.

Comment: The problem existed in Lo 4.0 as well and it was Unity issue. It was solved, but now it exists again... Ubuntu comes with LibreOffice preinstalled, it is pitty that so little effort is invested in order to make this office package working without problem.